# Dual Scrolling of two rich textboxs

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, richtextbox

I have two rich textboxs compareing data with very little changes between them.

I would like them to scroll together.

The scrolling must be synchronized. can any one show me how i would go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Check this Link [Synchronized-RichTextBox-objects-or-how-to-scroll](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/199253/Synchronized-RichTextBox-objects-or-how-to-scroll)

```
public class SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
{
    public event vScrollEventHandler vScroll;
    public delegate void vScrollEventHandler(System.Windows.Forms.Message message);

    public const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
        {
            if (vScroll != null)
            {
                vScroll(msg);
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }

    public void PubWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'PubWndProc' and no extension method 'PubWndProc' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)